# MonoDevelop Addin Warning message creation

Tags: c#, monodevelop, add-in

I've developed an Addin for MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5 which outputs to the Build Output tab with code simliar to this (I've simplified):

```
MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ErrorListPad errorListPad = IdeApp.Workbench.GetPad<MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ErrorListPad> ().Content as MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Pads.ErrorListPad;
System.IO.TextWriter buildOutput = errorListPad.GetBuildProgressMonitor().Log;
buildOutput.WriteLine("Build Output Test");
```

This is great but what I really want to do is output a few of the messages to the Warnings tab within the Error List as well. I've seen the [API Documentation](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Articles/API_Overview) but am still not sure how to achieve this task.

Does anyone have any hints or tips on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to the TaskService.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.CustomTools/CustomToolService.cs#L185) of the generator tool doing so.

Comment: Thank you, that code did help, but in the end I found a project that was doing something so similar to what I was doing that I simply forked it and stuck it on Git Hub - https://github.com/mattlaver/Stylecop-Monodevelop-Addin